# Polynomial expansion need help

Tags: polynomials

What is the answer to this my calculator is giving me different answers

$$(-0.2511x^3 + 0.5766x^2 + 0.1744X + 2.7)^2$$

Comment: I wished you had provided the different answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(-0.2511x^3 + 0.5766x^2 + 0.1744X + 2.7)^2\\
=0.0630512 x^6-0.289569 x^5+0.332468 x^4-0.0875837 x^3 X-1.35594 x^3+0.201118 x^2 X+3.11364 x^2+0.0304154 X^2+0.94176 X+7.29$$
By introductory polynomial multiplication. Anything else is incorrect.

Assuming $X=x$, the polynomial, expanded, is
$$0.0630512 x^6-0.289569 x^5+0.244884 x^4-1.15482 x^3+3.14406 x^2+0.94176 x+7.29$$

Comment: @Amzoti I'll edit my answer to include that as a case.

Comment: @Amzoti See my edit.

Comment: thank you i have an extended question to this can you please help me out, much appreciation!